# pygame play sound as long button is pressed

Tags: python, audio, pygame

For my University Project I want to write a little, lets call it an "instrument".
So I want to play a sound (sine wave) as long as the assigned button is pressed.

What I have so far is like that:

```
#create a sine array with frequency, samplerate and duration:
def sine(freq, samplerate, duration):
  duration = duration * samplerate
  wave = [math.sin(2.0 * math.pi * freq * t / samplerate) for t in range(0, duration)]
  return numpy.array(wave)

# this is the point int the main loop where the sound has to be played
if key[pygame.K_p]:
  pygame.sndarray.make_sound(sine(440, 44100, duration).play()
```

The Problem is that if I press the button it plays for the duration I set and overlays it everytime the loop recognizes that I am pressing the button.

I think it should work with getting the current time and the time when I release the button but dont have any idea how to make it realize it.

Maybe you have some approaches for me.

Comment: Do you want it to play: 1. while the the button is pressed, 2. start when the button is pressed an run for a certain duration, 3. play for a duration equal to the time the button was pressed (but after it was released).

Comment: I want to start playing the sound and stopping it after I release the button, so as long as i press the button

Answer (score 0):

you could have the if statement that plays the sound only be processed every "duration" seconds, so that then last sound file has ended just as it starts the next one.

Also you could try using pygame.mixer.sound this way you could have any sound you want playing .  Then using the .play method you can have it play for like 10000 times and call stop when the button is released.

how i suggest testing for releasing and pressing the button is holding onto the last state of the button in another variable. ex.

pWasPressed = pygame.K_p

then have your if statement be

if (pWasPressed = false and pygame.K_p):

this will only trigger when you press down the key for the first time and not keep running the if statement every time that the loop runs.

hope that helps.

Comment: yes i thougt about that also but the thing is that I want to use a sine wave and the properity therefore is that I have a duration --- ths is what I think

Comment: are you able to stop the sound, ie pygame.sndarray.stop()? if so you could use the if statements (if pWasPressed ex..) to start and stop the sound with a stupidly long duration.

Comment: that would be an idea, the problem is that I want to change the frequency using a controller in the next step, so that would be no real solution

Comment: you could add the condition to the if statements so that it would check if the button was released or if the settings were changed...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the if statement to also check if the sound is currently playing.

```
# check the mixer is not engaged when the key is down
if key[pygame.K_p] and (not pygame.mixer.get_busy() ):
   <your sound>.play()
#  check if the mixer is engaged when the key is up
elif not key[pygame.K_p] and pygame.mixer.get_busy():
   <your sound>.stop()
```

For this you may want to create the sound at the beginning and store it in a variable, otherwise it will be difficult to reference it to stop later on.

Answer (score 0):

I was remaking an arcade game Donkey kong and I used this for the walk of mario

```
        if not pygame.mixer.get_busy():
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(walk)
```

This happens when it goes right or left, but to stop making the sound of the step (that is one second long with different step pitch) I put this as another if condition

```
        elif not keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or not keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            pygame.mixer.Sound.stop(walk)
```

It made the job perfectly.
I will post the repository of the game if I finish it. The game is not mine but  I want to fork it. https://github.com/formazione/DonkeyKong